# Bootstrap jumbotron full browser height issue

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap Jumbotron as per below code...

```
<div class="jumbotron">
     <div class="container">
        content here...
     </div>
</div>
```

The css makes sure the jumbotron finds browser height and fills it like this...

```
html,body {
height:100%;
}

.jumbotron {
height:100%;
}
```

My fixed navbar has a height of 60px and I want the jumbotron to have a margin-top: 60px so it starts 'below' the nav and not 'behind' the nav.

The problem is - this adds a 60px margin to the bottom of the jumbotron over the 100% height I have set. How can i remove this 60px margin it automatically adds to the bottom of the browser?

Comment: Bootstrap gives margin-bottom to `.jumbotron`. You have to give margin: 60px 0 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the fixed navbar, Bootstrap recommends [using top padding](http://jsfiddle.net/82wL6/27/) on the body for this:

```
body {
    padding-top: 60px; /* set this equal to navbar's height */
}
```

This is mentioned in the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top)

> **Body padding required**
>
> The fixed navbar will overlay your other content, unless you add
>   padding to the top of the . Try out your own values or use our
>   snippet below. Tip: By default, the navbar is 50px high.

Comment: Not trying to bust your chops, but I'm not seeing how it happens.

Comment: @isherwood: That looks right. `.jumbotron` starts exactly beneath the navbar, right?